# emacs nXML-mode hide subheadings error: Not in section

Tags: xml, emacs, nxml

Emacs nXML-mode keeps saying "byte-code: Not in section" error message when I try to run nxml-hide-subheadings, I'm not sure why.

The formatting is fine, when I run the validation command, it tells me "No more errors".

I also updated both nxml-section-element-name-regexp and nxml-heading-element-name-regexp to include tags that are supposed to be heading in my file, but this doesn't seems to change anything.

rng-what-schema command gives "vacuous schema".

nxml-forward/backward-elements runs fine.

As suggested, here is the xml file I was using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Product Version: Vivado v2014.3 (64-bit)              -->
<!--                                                         -->
<!-- Copyright 1986-2014 Xilinx, Inc. All Rights Reserved.   -->

<Project Version="7" Minor="2" Path="/home/caiz/dev/PDD/PDD.xpr">
  <DefaultLaunch Dir="$PRUNDIR"/>
  <Configuration>
    <Option Name="Id" Val="cdf7cd0b34644b3fad8429729cc39541"/>
    <Option Name="Part" Val="xc7k70tfbg676-1"/>
    <Option Name="CompiledLibDir" Val="$PCACHEDIR/compile_simlib"/>
    <Option Name="TargetLanguage" Val="VHDL"/>
    <Option Name="SimulatorLanguage" Val="VHDL"/>
    <Option Name="BoardPart" Val=""/>
    <Option Name="ActiveSimSet" Val="data_selector_sim"/>
    <Option Name="DefaultLib" Val="xil_defaultlib"/>
  </Configuration>
  <FileSets Version="1" Minor="31">
    <FileSet Name="TX_buffer_sim" Type="SimulationSrcs">
      <Filter Type="Srcs"/>
      <File Path="$PPRDIR/src/TX_buffer_RAM.vhd">
        <FileInfo>
          <Attr Name="ImportPath" Val="$PPRDIR/src/TX_buffer_RAM.vhd"/>
          <Attr Name="ImportTime" Val="1412826762"/>
          <Attr Name="UsedIn" Val="synthesis"/>
          <Attr Name="UsedIn" Val="simulation"/>
        </FileInfo>
      </File>
      <File Path="$PPRDIR/src/TX_buffer_RAM_tb.vhd">
        <FileInfo>
          <Attr Name="ImportPath" Val="$PPRDIR/src/TX_buffer_RAM_tb.vhd"/>
          <Attr Name="ImportTime" Val="1412826762"/>
          <Attr Name="UsedIn" Val="synthesis"/>
          <Attr Name="UsedIn" Val="simulation"/>
        </FileInfo>
      </File>
      <Config>
        <Option Name="DesignMode" Val="RTL"/>
        <Option Name="TopModule" Val="TX_buffer_RAM_tb"/>
        <Option Name="TopLib" Val="xil_defaultlib"/>
        <Option Name="SimMode" Val="post-implementation"/>
        <Option Name="SrcSet" Val=""/>
        <Option Name="XSimWcfgFile" Val="$PPRDIR/src/waveform/TX_buffer_RAM_tb_behav.wcfg"/>
      </Config>
    </FileSet>
  </FileSets> 
  <Simulators>
    <Simulator Name="XSim">
      <Option Name="Description" Val="Vivado Simulator"/>
    </Simulator>
    <Simulator Name="ModelSim">
      <Option Name="Description" Val="QuestaSim/ModelSim Simulator"/>
    </Simulator>
    <Simulator Name="IES">
      <Option Name="Description" Val="Incisive Enterprise Simulator (IES)"/>
    </Simulator>
    <Simulator Name="VCS">
      <Option Name="Description" Val="Verilog Compiler Simulator (VCS)"/>
    </Simulator>
  </Simulators>
  <Runs Version="1" Minor="9">
    <Run Id="synth_1" Type="Ft3:Synth" SrcSet="sources_1" Part="xc7k70tfbg676-1" ConstrsSet="constrs_1" Description="Vivado Synthesis Defaults" State="current" Dir="$PRUNDIR/synth_1">
      <Strategy Version="1" Minor="2">
        <StratHandle Name="Vivado Synthesis Defaults" Flow="Vivado Synthesis 2014"/>
        <Step Id="synth_design"/>
      </Strategy>
      <GeneratedRun Dir="$PRUNDIR" File="gen_run.xml"/>
    </Run>
    <Run Id="impl_1" Type="Ft2:EntireDesign" Part="xc7k70tfbg676-1" ConstrsSet="constrs_1" Description="Vivado Implementation Defaults" State="current" SynthRun="synth_1">
      <Strategy Version="1" Minor="2">
        <StratHandle Name="Vivado Implementation Defaults" Flow="Vivado Implementation 2014"/>
        <Step Id="init_design"/>
        <Step Id="opt_design"/>
        <Step Id="power_opt_design"/>
        <Step Id="place_design"/>
        <Step Id="post_place_power_opt_design"/>
        <Step Id="phys_opt_design"/>
        <Step Id="route_design"/>
        <Step Id="post_route_phys_opt_design"/>
        <Step Id="write_bitstream"/>
      </Strategy>
    </Run>
  </Runs>
</Project>
```

And here is the related emacs settings I have, I stripped it down to bare minimum:

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.

 '(nxml-heading-element-name-regexp "title\\|head\\|Project\\|Configuration\\|Filesets\\|Fileset\\|Simulators\\|Runs\\|Run")
 '(nxml-section-element-name-regexp "article\\|\\(sub\\)*section\\|chapter\\|div\\|appendix\\|part\\|preface\\|reference\\|simplesect\\|bibliography\\|bibliodiv\\|glossary\\|glossdiv\\|Project\\|Configuration\\|Filesets\\|Fileset\\|Simulators\\|Runs\\|Run"))
```

Comment: Do you have some sample code so that other forum participants can try running `nxml-hide-subheadings` to see if the error is reproducible?  You might also consider removing the byte-compiled file and enabling debugging to *hopefully* generate what may be a more useful indicator of the problem.  Sometimes things go awry when byte-compiling, and sometimes better error messages are available when using the raw source that is not byte-compiled.

Comment: @lawlist Thanks for the suggestion, just added a xml file and related emacs settings.